# Access - VBA invalid use of null

Tags: vba, ms-access, runtime-error

I'm writing the VBA code for a button in an Access form. I want the information inserted by the user to add a new record to a specific table, the table `Funcionario`. When I insert data only into the required fields, I get an error message if I have this line of code enabled:

```
Observacoes = Me.Observacoes.Value
```

The error says `Invalid use of Null`.

Here's the full code, that I'm working on:

```
Private Sub new_func_Click()

    Dim Id_Funcionario As Integer
    Dim Primeiro_Nome, Ultimo_Nome, NIF, Sexo, Morada, Localidade, Email, Contacto, Foto, Observacoes As String
    Dim Data_Nascimento, Data_contrato_i, Data_contrato_f As Date

    Id_Funcionario = Me.Id_Funcionario.Value
    Primeiro_Nome = Me.Primeiro_Nome.Value
    Ultimo_Nome = Me.Ultimo_Nome.Value
    NIF = Me.NIF.Value
    Data_Nascimento = Me.Data_Nascimento.Value
    Sexo = Me.Sexo.Value
    Morada = Me.Morada.Value
    Localidade = Me.Localidade.Value
    Email = Me.Email.Value
    Contacto = Me.Contacto.Value
    Data_contrato_i = Me.Data_contrato_i.Value
    Observacoes = Me.Observacoes.Value
    Foto = Me.Foto.Value
    Data_contrato_f = ""

    'If IdFunc, NIF and Data_contrato_i empty:

    If IsNull(Me.Id_Funcionario.Value) = True Or IsNull(Me.NIF.Value) = True Or IsNull(Me.Data_contrato_i.Value) = True Then
        MsgBox "Please insert data in the required fields", vbExclamation, "Warning"
    Else
        DoCmd.RunSQL "INSERT INTO Funcionario (Id_Funcionario, Primeiro_Nome, Ultimo_Nome, NIF, Data_Nascimento, Sexo, Morada, Localidade, Email, Contacto, Data_contrato_i, Data_contrato_f, Observacoes, Foto) VALUES ('" & Id_Funcionario & "', '" & Primeiro_Nome & "', '" & Ultimo_Nome & "', " & NIF & ", '" & Data_Nascimento & "', '" & Sexo & "', '" & Morada & "', '" & Localidade & "', '" & Email & "', '" & Contacto & "', '" & Data_contrato_i & "', '" & Data_contrato_f & "', '" & Observacoes & "', '" & Foto & "')"
    End If
End Sub
```

Can someone please help me? I don't know what I'm doing wrong, thank you.

Comment: The error message means that the forms control `Me.Observacoes` is `Null` (so no value has been entered yet).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This line

```
Dim Primeiro_Nome, Ultimo_Nome, NIF, Sexo, Morada, Localidade, Email, Contacto, Foto, Observacoes As String
```

only declares `Observacoes` as a `String`, all the others are `Variants`.  To have them all as strings you should use:

```
Dim Primeiro_Nome As String, Ultimo_Nome As String,....
```

A `Variant` can contain a `Null` value, while a `String` can't.

You could change the line to:

```
Observacoes = NZ(Me.Observacoes.Value,"")
```

which will replace a `Null` value with an empty string.

**Edit after answer accepted:**

As @Erik commented using [parameters](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/client-developer/access/desktop-database-reference/parameters-declaration-microsoft-access-sql) makes the process a whole lot simpler.  The parameters in the code below are `MyID` and `MyPrimeiro`, but you can use pretty much any text for the parameter name.

```
Private Sub new_func_Click()

    If IsNull(Me.Id_Funcionario) Or IsNull(Me.Primeiro_Nome) Then
        MsgBox "Please insert data in the required fields.", vbOKOnly + vbExclamation, "Warning"
    Else
        With CurrentDb.CreateQueryDef("", _
            "PARAMETERS MyID LONG, MyPrimeiro TEXT(255); " & _
            "INSERT INTO Funcionario (Id_Funcionario, Primeiro_Nome) VALUES (MyID, MyPrimeiro)")

            .Parameters("MyID") = Me.Id_Funcionario
            .Parameters("MyPrimeiro") = Me.Primeiro_Nome
            .Execute

        End With
    End If

End Sub
```

Comment: Remember that if you want to check `Observacoes` you'll need to use `If Observacoes = ""` rather than `If ISNULL(Obswervacoes)` (the `= TRUE` part isn't needed).

Comment: Note that you haven't solved the issue of string concatenation instead of using parameters and nulls. This will lead to OP storing zero-length strings in the database instead of actual null values, which will likely lead to unexpected results and trouble down the road. I strongly recommend preserving nulls and making sure never to use string concatenation when inserting data.

Comment: @ErikVonAsmuth Very good point - maybe I should have read the `RunSQL` statement to get it all in context.